# Etimologia/origine dell'espressione Che forte!

Tags: phrase-origin

Per rispondere a una domanda su un altro sito (Spanish.SE), stavo cercando l'origine dell'espressione "¡Qué fuerte!", che spesso viene utilizzata per esprimere sorpresa. Siccome non trovavo niente, ho fatto quello che faccio di solito quando voglio conoscere l'etimologia di un termine: compararlo con altre lingue romanze. Allora ho pensato all'espressione italiana "che forte!" e francese "trop fort!", ma queste decisamente vengono utilizzate in una maniera diversa, cioè per esprimere che qualcosa sia "fantastica", "stupenda". Queste accezioni, sebbene diverse da quella spagnola, sono anche interessanti, dato che si riferiscono a un senso che non è intrinseco al significato più evidente del termine "forte". Quindi:

- Si sa quando il termine "forte" ha cominciato a essere utilizzato col significato di "fantastico", e quale possa essere stata la ragione (leggasi relazione col significato originale)?
- Non so se questo sia *off-topic* ma, si sa se ci sia qualche relazione tra l'espressione francese "trop fort!" e l'espressione italiana "che forte!"?

---

Nota: qui c'è una spiegazione di un madre lingua francese sul significato di "trop fort":

> Title: **C'est trop fort!**
>   Q: I assume this expression means in English "It's too strong". But what I want to know is whether this is a commonly used expression in French that has another connotation. If someone wrote, "C'est trop fort!!" in response to something, what would you assume it to mean? Does it automatically have a bad or good connotation or would it depend on the context?
>
> A: It is very commonly used in an informal discussion to express one's enthusiasm about something, it is the equivalent of "It's awesome!" or "It's terrific!". Mostly used by young people.
>
> [WordReference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/cest-trop-fort.1231504/)

EDIT: [here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16789/de-d%C3%B3nde-viene-la-expresi%C3%B3n-qu%C3%A9-fuerte) is the original question and [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19301/origine-%C3%A9tymologie-de-l-expression-trop-fort) is the same question on French.SE.

Comment: Mi sembra una domanda molto interessante. Secondo quello che ho trovato nel libro *Acqua in bocca! Tutto quello che vorresti dire in italiano... come lo direbbe un italiano!* di Roberto Bortoluzzi (Edizioni Casa delle lingue, Barcellona, 2015), si può anche dire semplicemente "Forte!". Ecco la spiegazione di questo libro: "Un altro aggettivo a cui il gergo giovanile ha dato un senso diverso rispetto a quello della lingua standard: forte è tutto quello che è interessante e degno di ammirazione."

Comment: **Esempio di uso che appare nel libro:** -- Perché stasera non andiamo in spiaggia con le chitarre? Potremmo anche fare il bagno al chiaro di luna.  -- Forte! Sì, dai, andiamo!

Comment: Purtroppo, il libro non dice niente sull'origine di questo uso dell'aggettivo "forte", ma sembra avere un significato molto simile al francese "C'est trop fort!".

Comment: @Charo Grazie per l'input! La questione della coincidenza delle due espressioni in francese e italiano mi incuriosisce molto. Sarà che sia appersa in una lingua e poi esportata all'altra, o forse ci sia un motivo etimologico che spieghi tutt'e due? Vediamo se qualcuno sa qualcosa.

Comment: **"Che forte!"** è utilizzato in italiano come l'hai detto tu, per significare che quello è piaciuto alla persona, come "that's awesome" in inglese. In portoghese (slang), io lo direi **"Que daora"**, per esempio. Concentrandomi sulla domanda: forte ha significato positivo, quindi la relazione c'è. Quanto al francese, non saprei dire, soltanto che "trop" è molto simile a "troppo", in italiano, e probabilmente possiede lo stesso significato.

Answer (score 2):

Non so esattamente da quando forte sia stato utilizzato per indicare qualcosa di divertente, sicuramente almeno dalla mia infanzia, come testimonia questo film di Verdone:

[image: Troppo Forte]

[Troppo Forte, 1986](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Troppo_forte)

---

Spostamento simile hanno avuto anche i termini [*gagliardo*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gagliardo/) e [*ganzo*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ganzo/), rispettivamente nel dialetto romano ("che gajardo!") e toscano ("che ganzo!"), che indicano appunto oggetto o situazione per cui si prova manifesto entusiasmo.