# Exact meaning of colloquial expression "che forte!"

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, phrase-request, interjections

Buongiorno,

Volevo sapere se qualcuno mi poteva fare la definizione esatta del'espressione colloquiale "che forte!".

Penso che significhi "secondo me, questo è piacevole o interessante e attira gli altri".

Non ho trovato questa espressione nel dizionario, l'ho sentita varie volte, ma non saprei come spiegarla.

Comment: È circa equivalente all'inglese *What a great thing!*

Comment: Domanda correlata: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/etimologia-origine-dellespressione-che-forte

Comment: Anche qualcosa come “Cool!”. E vedi anche la domanda già citata.

Comment: The English equivalent is "Cool!"

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @RiccardoDeContardi! Questo è stato già detto in un commento. Qui ci aspettiamo una risposta un po' più elaborata. Per questa ragione il tuo post è stato convertito in un commento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ecco la spiegazione sull'espressione "Che forte!" o semplicemente "Forte!" che si trova nel libro *Acqua in bocca! Tutto quello che vorresti dire in italiano... come lo direbbe un italiano!* di Roberto Bortoluzzi (Edizioni Casa delle lingue, Barcellona, 2015):

> **Forte**      Un altro aggettivo a cui il gergo giovanile ha dato un senso diverso rispetto a quello della lingua standard: forte è tutto quello che è interessante e degno di ammirazione. 
>   **Esempio di uso:**
>       – Perché stasera non andiamo in spiaggia con le chitarre? Potremmo anche fare il bagno al chiaro di luna. 
>       – Forte! Sì, dai, andiamo!

Comment: The answer is perfectly correct. I'd just add that there a large number of alternative expressions that colloquialy mean the same: fico, figo, togo, ganzo, una bomba, etc...